# 2D sunrise in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, mathematics, viewport

I see a lot of guides on how to create sunrise in 3D space, but I can't find much information on how to do it in 2D. In 3D, you rotate a lightsource around itself, but in 2D, I need to move the object from the bottom of the screen to the top of the screen and reset it.

I can make a day cycle and position the sun sprite at the top right corner like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SunController : MonoBehaviour {

    [Range(0, 1)]
    public float currentTimeOfDay = 0;

    private Vector3 initialPosition;


    void Start ()
    {
        // Set initial position
        initialPosition = new Vector3 (.9f, .9f, 10 /* camera is at -10 */);
        transform.position = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(initialPosition);
    }

    void Update () {

        currentTimeOfDay += (Time.deltaTime / 120) * 1;

        if (currentTimeOfDay >= 1)
            currentTimeOfDay = 0;
    }
}
```

When the timer hits 1, a day is completed.

I somehow need to map this to the top and bottom of the screen so when the timer is at ~0.5f (remember: it ranges from 0 to 1, but as a float with 7 decimals = 0.0000000 -> 0.5709517 -> 1.0000000), the sprite should be half way up the screen etc.

How would I go about doing this? I figure Mathf.Clamp might work here, but I can't get my head around it for this case.

Screenshot:

[image: Sun]

Comment: I'm having trouble interpreting this question.  It might be clearer if you draw a quick mock up of the path you want the sun to take, and the time values that correspond to the key positions.

Comment: Hi @KellyThomas - basically I just need it to go from the bottom of the screen, to the top of the screen, taking into consideration that the timer currentTimeOfDay goes from 0 to 1 .. so if we're at 0.5, the cube should be half way up the screen and 1 it would be at the top. Does that make sense? If not, I can try drawing something :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using a sine or cosine curve to determine the position at the particular time. This would produce an output like,

[image: Several Sine curves]

Where the zero line is assumed to be ground level (so when the sun is below the ground it is not visible).

This also makes it relatively easy to adjust how much time is spent in night or day. Use

```
GetSunHeight(){
    currentTimeOfDay += Time.deltaTime;
    float dayFrequency = 1/dayLength;
    sunHeight = Mathf.Sin(currentTimeOfDay * 2 * Mathf.pi * dayFrequency);

}
```

This allows you to set the length per cycle. I.e. if `dayLength = 120` then a full day-night cycle should take 120 s.